# Random search in r-caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, hyperparameters, mxnet

I recently came across the random search option in caret's `trainControl()` Funktion. How does caret generate the parameters and is there a ways to provide some sort of user-specific input (e.g. a distributions where the parameters are sampled from)? On the [website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/random.html) I only found this quote:

> built-in models contained in caret contain code to generate random tuning parameter combinations

For example, I tried `mxnet` with caret and random search:

```
# Train control with random search
rs_control <- trainControl(method = "boot", 
                           number = 2, 
                           search = "random",
                           verboseIter = TRUE
                           )

# Training
model_fit <- train(form = y ~ .,
                   data = df_train,
                   method = "avMxnet",
                   preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                   tuneLength = 20,
                   trControl = rs_control
                   )
```

Using this code, caret sampled reasonable values for the number of neurons on the first layer and other parameters (learningrate, momentum, dropout and repeats) but keep the second/third layer constant at zero. Is there a ways to tell caret to sample for all three layers with a uniform distribution from e.g. [25, 150]?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not sure what version of `caret` you are using since that model is not available

```
> library(caret)
> getModelInfo("avMxnet")
Error in getModelInfo("avMxnet") : 
  That model is not in caret's built-in library
```

This is with the CRAN version caret_6.0-70.

I'm assuming that you are using the code on github. If that is the case, you can alter the `grid` code and have it generate any random search grid that you like.

Comment: I am using CRAN version caret_6.0-68 and `getModelInfo("avMxnet")` ist actually working for me.. Maybe you have to install mxnet in the first place... What do you mean with 'the code on github'?

Comment: I'd love to have mxnet in caret! ;)

Comment: As far as I can say, it is already supported: http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html